# Sign in redirect to the page where he were lastly in Rails Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to have a sign in page that redirects to user the last page he were before sign in. How could I do it in Rails. Do I need to override after_sign_in_path for each link of how?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes, you will need to override the `after_sign_in_path` The simplest method I have found to do so is as follows:

Inside of your application controller you will need to add two methods,

```
  include SessionsHelper
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    case resource_or_scope
    when :user, User
      store_location = session[:return_to]
      clear_stored_location
      (store_location.nil?) ? requests_path : store_location.to_s
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def check_login
    if !anyone_signed_in?
      deny_access
    end
  end
```

First we override the `after_sign_in_path` to save our new stored location which we pull from the Rails session into our `store_location` which we will define in our `SessionsHelper`. Next we create a method that we can use as a `before_filter` in any controller we want to use this on.

Next, set up `sessions_helper.rb`

```
module SessionsHelper

  def deny_access
    store_location
    redirect_to new_user_session_path
  end

  def anyone_signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  private

    def store_location
      session[:return_to] = request.fullpath
    end

    def clear_stored_location
      session[:return_to] = nil
    end

end
```

Here we're just defining the methods we used inside of our application controller, which should all be pretty self explanatory. Just remember to use `before_filter :check_login` before any other before filters in the controllers you are wanting to remember the previous path for.